# How to extract a complete sentence from text from start of that sentence using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the complete sentence here (The rain in SPAIN stays) with the mentioned code below. I am new to programming please help . Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays. mainly in the plain";
            var n = str.indexOf("rain");
            var res = str.substr(n, str.indexOf(".") - n);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `myFunction()`, you are not calling it.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays. mainly in the plain"; 
    var n = str.indexOf("rain");
var res = str.substr(n, str.indexOf(".")-n);    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
myFunction();//HERE IS THE CALL
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function first make a call to it like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays. mainly in the plain"; 
    var n = str.indexOf("rain");
var res = str.substr(n, str.indexOf(".")-n);    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
myFunction();// Call to the function
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or you can even trigger the function on some event like onclick of a button or onload.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the complete sentence here (The rain in SPAIN stays).

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays. mainly in the plain";
    var n = str.indexOf("The");            // need to find index of "The" not rain"
    var res = str.substr(n, str.indexOf(".") - n);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}

myFunction();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zacu3rmg/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using regular expressions.

You know for a fact that you code contains "**some text. some text**"

```
var myRegex = /(\w+),\s*(\w+)/;
var myArray = myRegex.exec(str);
```

- `\w+` means any one or more letter word character.

In your case first `\w+` is: The rain in SPAIN stays and the second `\w+` is: mainly in the plain

- `,` is the explicit comma
- `\s*` means 0 or more white spaces

You also said you are new to programming. As a newcomer, I guess you are not familiar with regular expressions. Regular expressions are very useful in string manipulation and I have provided you with a link for regular expressions specifically in javascript that will help you start.

[Regular Expressions in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)